# Does linear dependence imply span across $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am not sure if I am asking a stupid question but I will ask anyway.

Does linear dependence of a set of vectors mean that they span across $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ is an integer larger or equal to 2? Or does linear independence of a set of vectors mean it spans across $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thank you.

Comment: Linear independence of a set of *exactly $n$ vectors* in $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies they span $\mathbb{R}^n$, because very basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ has exactly $n$ vectors in it. But just “linear independence of a set” is not sufficient, if there aren’t enough vectors in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear independence and span are not dependent on each other in any of the ways listed. For example, the vectors $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)$ are linearly independent, but not spanning in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (note that every linear combination has a $0$ in the third coordinate). Also, the vectors $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)$ are linearly dependent, but also not spanning.

There is one thing we can say. Suppose we have a vector space $V$ with a known dimension $n$ (e.g. $\Bbb{R}^n$) and a list of vectors $B$. Consider the following conditions:

- $B$ is linearly independent,
- $B$ spans $V$,
- $B$ contains $n$ vectors.

Then, any two of the above conditions implies the third. So, for example, every linearly independent list of $n$ vectors also spans the space.

Comment: That was quick. Especially for a new user. Good answer though

Comment: But what about a finite vector set and the linear combinations of them to produce *any* vector in the space to span across R. Doesn't that mean that the finite set of vectors spans R if the linear combinations you make with them can produce any vector in R, regardless of linear independence/dependence?

Comment: Also, to my understanding, linear dependence does not imply span across R. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mathaholic Yes, that's what it means to span the space: every vector in the space can be written as some linear combination of these vectors, and this has no bearing on linear (in)dependence. As for your other question, yes linear dependence does not imply spanning, see my three vector example above. In terms of the specific vector space $\Bbb{R}$, you can have the set $\{0\}$, which is linearly dependent, but not spanning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time.